# how to store an array via jquery data method and add to that array values?

Tags: jquery

how to store an array via jquery data method and add to that array?

Comment: Are you storing it on/with an element, or you just want a general array to use?

Answer (score 11):

Since references to arrays are stored, you can do it like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
$.data(elem, "myArray", array);

// and later
$.data(elem, "myArray").push(4, 5, 6); 

// and later
console.log($.data(elem, "myArray"));
//-> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Should be simple task:

```
$('#someelement').data('myarray', []);

// somewhere else
$('#someelement').data('myarray').push('foo');

// access
console.log( $('#someelement').data('myarray')[0] );
```

Comment: Why not a global variable if you're just storing it on body? :) I have my doubts that `.data()` or `$.data()` is even appropriate here...

Comment: @NickCraver: I modified it for your well-being :p

Answer (score 0):

```
  var array=[1,3,5];
  var count=7;

   $('#id').data('array').push(count);
```

Comment: You should set `array` as the data of the element. Otherwise you'd be pushing to undefined.